# Android app published but google play shows URL not found

Tags: android, google-play-console, publishing

I published my app in console. Everything went successful (listing, signing apk..). Finally app status came to PRODUCTION. According to google, if app status is production, it means that users can download the app from play store. But if i click view on play store, it shows URL not found. It's already more than 10 hours. Still i get the same message. Any help ?
[Screen shot of app status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV5kG.png)

[Google play URL not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV4xp.png)

Comment: As per the screenshot it is in review

Comment: Hey @PalaniappanS, your app is still under review. The URL will only work when it will be reviewed successfully, for now, the URL is the fixed address google has assigned to you based on their app URL syntax. Please wait for at  least 7-15 days to let it review. It may take more than 15 days also because they are taking too much time because of the pandemic.

Answer (score 1):

Get more info here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en

As per your case and the screenshot provided, your app still "In review".

Excerpt from the above URL:

> Note: For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to
> thoroughly review your app to help better protect users. This may
> result in review times of up to seven days or longer in exceptional
> cases. You’ll receive a notification on your app's Dashboard about how
> long this should take.

So for now, you can only wait.

Answer (score 0):

It will show after 5-7 days. Due to corona it's getting late in few days your app will start showing on google play store